# Send multiple JSON objects through AJAX/jQuery returns me an "undefined" array (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, json

### The goal

Send `[{"ID": 1, "Name": "XBOX"}, {"ID": 2, "Name": "Playstation 3"}]` via `$.ajax()` using jQuery.

### The problem

I have this:

```
[...]

var object = $.parseJSON(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "laboratory.php",
    data: object,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

And, in `laboratory.php`:

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
```

And finally, the return **via console** is:

```
Array
(
    [undefined] => 
)
```

This is what the `data`'s variable means:

```
[{"ID": 1, "Name": "XBOX"}, {"ID": 2, "Name": "Playstation 3"}]
```

And this is what `object` means (by Chrome's console):

```
[Object, Object]
```

Can someone give me an idea?

Comment: you are POSTING data, have you looked in the $_POST structure? since you're passing an array of object o jquery, jquery will attempt to turn that into a string of form params.

Comment: Are you saying me to debug with `print_r($_POST);`? If yes, then I already did and the return is the same.

Comment: What exactly do you want to send to the server? json, or post params

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using JSON.stringify:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "laboratory.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(object), // using stringify
    success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works! But it's kinda weird having to stringify the JSON object while the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) say that the `data` parameter can be a plain object... Perhaps a jQuery version issue?

Comment: Glad you got it working! :) Maybe something is buggy about the jQuery `$.parseJSON()` method, maybe it isn't passing a plain javascript object?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem. passing your array of objects to `$.param()` (which is what jQuery does internally with `data:` that isn't a string) results in `"undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined"` which is exactly what you are getting back from php. Your array simply is in a format that jQuery can't understand. Since what you actually want to send is json, don't use `$.parseJSON` because it'll turn your json into an array and what you really want is just a string.

```
//var object = $.parseJSON(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "laboratory.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: My  `$_REQUEST` is now empty, Kevin.

Comment: odd... it should be a string... Though, you can force it to be in `$_POST` by doing `data: {json: data}` you'll see it at `$_POST["json"]` are you sure `data` is what you think it is?

Comment: I saw that, but if you `console.log(data)`, does it give you the json string you are expecting?

Comment: This is the string: `[{"ID": 1, "Name": "XBOX}, {"ID": 2, "Name": "Playstation 3"}]`

Comment: is that a copy paste error? the `"XBOX},`? it's in your question that way too. Really shouldn't affect the outcome though, since so far we haven't done anything other than treat it as a string.

Comment: at this point i'm starting to think the error must be elsewhere, everything looks like it should be working..

Comment: single result asin, `[{"ID": 1, "Name": "XBOX"}]`?

Comment: Yes, "asin", hehe. Actually, if I fetch the return of the database with `mysqli_fetch_row` everything goes well. But if I fetch as object or array... Doh! An error appears!

Comment: that really should make no difference if data is a string... even if it were "somerandomstring that isn't json!" it should work.

Comment: Ah, so the jquery side of this is working now? i thought your php handling of the request was just `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>` or similar...

Comment: Kevin, probably was my bad, but this string (`[{"ID": 1, "Name": "XBOX"}, {"ID": 2, "Name": "Playstation 3"}]`) is returned by a database. I was using `mysqli_fetch_row()` and I've changed to `mysqli_fetch_array()/object()` and then the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple data, getJSON is better in my opinion:

```
$.getJSON('laboratory.php', function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key, val) {
            //Getting the value of id
            val["ID"];
            //Getting the value of name
            val["NAME"];
             //DO whatever u want.
            });
});
```

Comment: The "PHP code" is a simple multidimensional array with `utf8_encode(json_encode($array))`. And this is the `data`.

Comment: I reallized after posting, sorry about that. I had the same problem so I decided to try getJSON.